# Deployed react app to localhost:3000 but its saying "This site can’t be reached" though its shown in terminal that app is deployed at localhost:3000

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm

Everything looks fine with my code but when deployed to localhost it's showing,

I even tried disabling all the components, npm install but no.

[image]

terminal, it's looking fine

[image]

Dependencies

[image]

Browser Console

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Can you send the photo of the browser's console?Maybe we can see
Node js environment doesnt show you the errors because react works on client's browser.

Comment: I don't know why but the app is running well on localhost, thanks for being a generous brother.

Comment: the problem shows up again, after running react successfully on localhost:3000, I ran node API on localhost:5000 when I came back and reload localhost:3000 it's gone, I tried closing the connection on 5000 and also restarting but no use.

Comment: I searched and find the only solution to this problem is restarting, nobody seems to know the cause.

Comment: Hahhaha that 's a way too :D